# Migrated question was returned to original site, reputation lost?

Tags: support, migrated-questions, migration-rejection

This [question on Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28384/is-the-php-method-md5-secure-can-it-be-used-for-passwords#question) was originally migrated to StackOverflow. StackOverflow reverted the migration as off-topic. The only answer to the question had accumulated 90 rep (9 upvotes) before the migration was undone. Those seem to have disappeared. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: (As an aside: the reputation will also disappear if the question is deleted, which might happen soonish?)

Comment: [The answer and question in question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10098272/1114), for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected behavior.  From the blog post "[Reputation and Historical Archives](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)":

> First, if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you
> should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets
> deleted. “Worthwhile” here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days

So in this case, because the second condition isn't fulfilled, the reputation is lost.

This is intentional, as the lack of reputation loss is for answers given to the site in good faith at a time when the site ran with different tolerances for what is appropriate and what is not.

If someone contributes an answer *today* with the knowledge that the question (or answer) is not appropriate for the site, the point is that they shouldn't gain reputation for it, as it's inherently not in good faith (we have to make *some* assumptions about what people do and don't know, otherwise, we'll be trying to reward rep back to *everyone* who says "oh, I did it in good faith").

Comment: Hmm... I agree that it's [by-design], but it seems a bit unfair that the original answer (and its earned rep) were lost due to an ill-advised migration, so I've undeleted it while the community decides whether or not to keep the migrated question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Blame stupid Community (or one of the devs).  I don't program the thing. =P